# Rename Label Behavior for Service Appointment Object Fields

Tags: tab, label, standard-field, rename-symbol

I am trying to change label of the Address Field on Service Appointment Object. So under the rename tabs and label , I have changed the address label to Service Address. However the new value does not reflect on the record detail page.

Further, in the same list of standard fields labels for Service Appointment, I see fields/labels which I am unable to find in the list of fields. eg: Additional Information .

However, for other fields eg:Description I was able to relabel using the same steps.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=cannot-rename-address-field-on-field-service-lightning-objects&Id=a1p3A0000003fcu

"This Known Issue is currently in review by our Product Team; however, a workaround has not yet been provided." - from Salesforce.